# Check if page is vertical using PyPDF2?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, pypdf

Is there a way to check to see if a PDF page is vertical using PyPDF2?

Ideally, there would be method `pdfReader.getPage(0).isVertical()` that returns `true` or `false`, but I can't find anything in the [PageObject docs](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PageObject.html)

I am attempting to merge a watermark on top of the first page of the a PDF, but it only looks right if the PDF is in vertical orientation.

Was hoping to do the following.

```
if (not (pdfReader.getPage(0).isVertical())):
    pdfReader.getPage(0).rotateClockwise(90)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to guarantee my first page, `firstPage = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFile).getPage(0)`, was vertical by using a combination of a two things.

#### Code

I calculated `isVertical` by using the coordinates of upper right and lower right.

```
def isVertical(page):
    page = page.mediaBox
    return page.getUpperRight_x() - page.getUpperLeft_x() < page.getUpperRight_y() - page.getLowerRight_y()
```

If the page was landscape, I rotate it by 90 degrees left, this could cause the page to be upside down, but at least it is vertical. If the pdf page is rotated, rotate it back.

```
if (not isVertical(firstPage)):
    firstPage.rotateCounterClockwise(90)

if (firstPage.get('/Rotate')):
    firstPage.rotateCounterClockwise(firstPage.get('/Rotate'))
```